# Convert ushort to string

Tags: c#

I have a ushort that consists of two bytes.

15 14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0

Y = bits 10-0, twos complement mantissa integer.

N = bits 15-11, twos complement integer.

X = Y * 2^N

I need to ouput X as a string.

This is what I have tried:

```
    private string ConvertLinearToString(ushort data)
    {
        int N;
        int Y;
        int X;

        N = Convert.ToInt16(GetBitRange((byte)data, 0, 5));
        Y = Convert.ToInt16(GetBitRange((byte)data, 6, 11));
        X = Convert.ToInt16(Y * Math.Pow(2, (double)N));

        return Convert.ToString(result);            
    }

    private byte GetBitRange(byte b, int offset, int count)
    {
        return Convert.ToByte((b >> offset) & ((1 << count) - 1));
    }
```

I'm stuck trying to convert the GetBitRange() formula to use ushort and also how to handle the twos complement.

Comment: Bitwise operations. Give it a try yourself, and if you're still stuck, show us where.

Comment: GetBitRange should work for Int16s simply by changing the return type and the argument b to Int16, an replacing Convert.ToByte with a cast to Int16.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the two's complement behavior by using a left shift to throw away bits you don't want followed by a right shift to sign extend.  If you implement GetBitRange using 32-bit integers like this:

```
private static int GetBitRange(int data, int offset, int count)
{
    return data << offset >> (32 - count);
}
```

Then just let the ushorts get converted to ints in ConvertLinearToString:

```
private static string ConvertLinearToString(ushort data)
{
    var n = GetBitRange(data, 16, 5);
    var y = GetBitRange(data, 21, 11);
    var value = y * Math.Pow(2, n);
    return value.ToString();
}
```

Comment: This seems to work. Given the 10-bit integer `0x200` we receive `-1024` when passing it to `GetBitRange`.

Comment: It looks like you got `n` and `y` backwards and the method name is different between your two code samples.

Comment: @ChaosPandion: Thanks!  It should be fixed now.  I must have changed the method name between copying one snippet and copying the other (not sure why).

Comment: @Quartermeister - No problem, if I can't remember how to do twos-complement properly the least I can do is peer-review your work.

Comment: I forgot to mention that Y is  a two's complement mantissa.  Could you show me how to do that?

Comment: @Robert: The left-shift right-shift in GetBitRange should sign-extend the mantissa just as well as the exponent.  Is there something else you need to do with the values?  Do you have a sample value that doesn't convert properly?

Comment: I have data = 0xD0B7

Supposed to return 2.86

Comment: @Robert: I had an off-by-one error in the call for y.  The first bit of the mantissa should be 21, not 22.

Answer (score 1):

Just covert your unsigned short to an integer and use the method to do the conversion.

```
ushort u = 10;
string s = Convert.ToString((int)u);
```

This solution is reasonably safe from overflow. There maybe some future version of C# where this operation would no longer be safe.